# Create a shortcut for an item on services menu in Ventura

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, services

I installed a translation app that does better translations than Apple’s built-in translator or translate.google.com.  It added an option to the global services menu to translate selected text.  Since the item is at the bottom of a long submenu of services, I’d like to make a keyboard shortcut for it.  In a web search, I found lots of pages about shortcuts, but only two that looked helpful:

“Make tech easier” says:

> In addition to enabling a certain option, you can also choose to add a
> specific keyboard shortcut.  By doing so, you can easily use the
> option anywhere in macOS without opening the Services menu.  To do
> this, click on “none” next to the option you want to add a shortcut to
> and press the desired keys together.

“[Make use of](https://www.maketecheasier.com/add-options-macos-services-menu/)” says:

> To create a shortcut for a service, click on the placeholder text that
> reads none next to the service in question. The text should then
> change into an Add Shortcut button.  Click on it and then hit the
> keyboard shortcut you want to use. That should assign the shortcut to
> the corresponding service.

**But neither works in Ventura (13.1).  How do we do it now?  (Or can we?)**

Using `defaults read com.apple.ServicesMenu.Services`, I figured out that I need to change an empty `NSKeyEquivalent` to `NSKeyEquivalent = { default = "$^@T"; en = "$^@T"; };` but from `man defaults` I can only see how to replace the entire plist for com.apple.ServicesMenu.Services.  That seems too risky.  But I located `/System/Volumes/Data/Users/(user)/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ServicesMenu.Services.plist` and opened it in Xcode, then found that I don't know how to add a sub-dictionary with the contents and name shown above.

Comment: "neither works"… what doesn't work? You can't add the shortcut, that item is not in the list, you don't see the shortcut added to the menu item…?

Comment: Neither of the cited/quoted pre-Ventura instructions works.  Click on the "none" and I'm not offered any entry field.  If I press a key combo anyway, nothing happens (unless it is an already defined shortcut).

Comment: OK, so that changes the entire question to "The key command field in Shortcuts isn't allowing new entires in Ventura - any workaround?"

Comment: Maybe.  Except there is no "key command field."  One workaround is to research how to edit the plist with Xcode.  A task I wouldn't have found daunting as a software engineer.  But I'm reluctant to come out of retirement after all these years.  :-)

Comment: …but you're making an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)  out of it. The field is missing, so rather than ask about the field, you're asking about what you think you might have to do to circumvent the issue another way.

Comment: Exactly.  I said exactly that and put it in bold.

Comment: Sorry but you didn't. You said "it doesn't work" which says nothing at all, hence my initial comment.

Comment: I repeat: "How do we do it now? (Or can we?)"

Comment: You start by re-casting your question to make it apparent which bit "doesn't work" & what you need a solution to, rather than all the irrelevant preamble about needing some translator… & two paragraphs of 'help page'.